# Can we create separate repositories for development, QA and production in TFS 2008/2010

Tags: tfs, production

We want to create different repositories for Development , QA and production code.

1. Is it possible to create separate repositories for the code, and access them at same time so that we can have control over all the code?
2. What is the standard way we follow to store and access development , QA and prodcution code?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to have a single team project collection with a team project for all of your code. Within that team project, you would set up a "Main" or "Trunk" with a branch for QA and a sub-branch off the QA branch for Development.

Comment: for more recommendations on branching see the branching guide at codeplex: http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/